# Getting months to display in order in through Angular Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iterator, angularjs-directive

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jelatin/Nmh3n/6/)

I'm trying to build a table using Angular's ng-repeat directive that displays two years of data:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
January  |  jan text this year   |  jan text last year  
February |  feb text this year   |  feb text last year  
March    |  march text this year |  march text last year
--------------------------------------------------------
```

What I end up with is:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
January  |  feb text this year   |  feb text last year  
February |  jan text this year   |  jan text last year  
March    |  march text this year |  march text last year
--------------------------------------------------------
```

I have an object with two years of data.

```
$scope.data = {
    thisYear: {
        January: 'jan text this year',
        February: 'feb text this year',
        March: 'march text this year'
        // etc..
    },
    lastYear: {
        January: 'jan text last year',
        February: 'feb text last year',
        March: 'march text last year'
        // etc..
    }
};
```

As well as a simple array: `$scope.months = ['January', 'February', 'March'];`

The months are easy, and work fine:

```
<div ng-repeat="month in months">{{ month }}</div>
```

The data, though, doesn't work as intended:

```
<div ng-repeat="d in data.thisYear">{{ d || "none" }}</div>
```

The data is iterated in alphabetical order, meaning the month's data doesn't line up. Since Angular data binding does not allow the use of primitive types, I can't solve it with multidimensional arrays.

I feel like I'm overlooking something stupid and small, I know I could get this done easily outside of Angular, but I'm trying to work within their system.  Perhaps a custom directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do each column by looping months

```
<div ng-repeat="month in months">{{ data.lastYear[month] || "none" }}</div>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AwuLq/)**</kbd>

Personally I would restructure data into something like

```
[{year: 2013, months:[{month: 'val', text:'val'},{month: 'val', text:'val'}....]},{ year: 2012:.....}]
```

Your comment about not being able to do this with arrays is off track. Objects don't have order, whereas arrays do

Comment: You're correct about me being off-track with Objects/Arrays.  Although I was specifically confused about not being able to use arrays due to a similar question which talked about not being able to use primitive types in the handlebars.

I like the current data structure a little better because there's significantly less repetition, but I appreciate the alternate viewpoint.

Comment: don't let JSON repetition fool you...is very helpful having object properties when writing angular apps. My solution for your situation is not very extendable for larger data. Consider for example what happens after new years

Comment: That's actually good to know.  Although I'm doing it this way because I have to add up all the data to get a total value for each month, so I ended up using arrays and prototyping an Array.sum() method, which seemed more efficient than looping through objects, checking for the right year and month, then adding.

I think some of the reasoning for the data structure is being lost because I boiled the problem down to its most basic elements for posting.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just change your data structure so you're iterating over a single array which contains all the information you need? Something like this:

```
$scope.data = [
    { month: 'January', thisYear: 'jan text this year', lastYear: 'jan text last year' },
    { month: 'February', thisYear: 'feb text this year', lastYear: 'feb text last year' },
    { month: 'March', thisYear: 'mar text this year', lastYear: 'mar text last year' },
    // etc..
];
```